# Async Express Router Function to MongoClient

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, asynchronous, post

I'm using Nodejs Express, the router middleware, in this case, MongoDB and using the POST method via JQuery ajax. Does anyone know why the
**router.post** doesn't call, but a **.get** works.
Does anyone know why the router.post
doesn't get triggered when called as a Promise/async.

Async route here doesn't get called on ajax post.

```
async function asyncMain() {
  const uri = "mongodb endpoint";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri)

try {
    await client.connect().then(console.log('Connected to MongoDB'));

    //keeps awaiting cause it never executes.
    await pushToDB(client)
    //all mongoClient functions work with await here
    //Express http Post doesn't work with await here

} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
} finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

asyncMain().catch(console.error);

async function pushToDB(client) {
router.post('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    
    const result = await client.db('user').collection('notes').insertOne(req.body);
    console.log(`Results ${ result.insertedId }`);
  })
}
```

I tried using this async Middleware implementation with no results.
Such as wrapping the post function's callback in asyncMiddleware to no avail.

```
 const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
 (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch(next);
 };
```

My working sync function for reference.

```
function main() {
   const uri = "mongodb endpoint";
   const client = new MongoClient(uri)

   client.connect().then(console.log('connected to DB'));
   router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    
   const result = client.db('user').collection('notes').insertOne(req.body);
   console.log(`Results ${ result.insertedId }`);
  })
}
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused, why do you want an ansyc `post` callback method ? I'm not entirely sure you can.. the function you are returning is a callback in itself, your code looks like its returning a promise of a promise..

Comment: As @Pogrindis has stated, its a bit confusing what you are trying to do here :) A few things but it looks like you are connecting to mongo with each request, you probably don't want to do that, connect once and reuse that connection. Next the route should be a route not part of a function, that defeats the purpose really unless you wanted to post back to another route but at that point you could just use http request, but really if its part of the same application that makes no sense because you can just access the same connections in the app. Maybe you can give more context as to the flow?